# Solving ODE using integrating factors with integrator which integrate integrand with image function

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am currently reading this pdf file of [Solving Differential Equations with Integrating Factors](https://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-ode.pdf)

**BEGIN OF QUOTE**

[image]

**END OF QUOTE**

$$  x^3 \frac{  dy  }{  dx  } + 3 x^{2} y= \exp\left( x\right)  $$

$$ A:= \int_{ }^{ } \left( x^3 \frac{dy}{dx}+3 x^2 y  \right)  \,dx  = \int_{ }^{ } \exp\left(x\right)  \,dx   $$

$~ A ~$ must be $~ yx^3 ~$

$$A= \int_{ }^{ } \left( x^3 \frac{  dy  }{ dx   }  \right)  \,dx  + \int_{ }^{ } \left( 3x^2 y\right)  \,dx = \exp\left(x\right)+C    $$

$$ = \int_{ }^{ } x^3  \,dy +  \int_{ }^{ } \left( 3x^2 y\right)  \,dx  $$

$$ \left( x^3y \right) '= 3x^2y+y'x^3 $$

$$  \left( x^3y \right) '-y'x^3= 3x^2y $$

$$  \therefore ~~ A=\int_{ }^{ } x^3 \,dy + \int_{ }^{ } \left( \left( x^3y \right) '-y'x^3 \right)  \,dx    $$

$$ = \int_{ }^{ } x^3 \,dy + \int_{ }^{ } \left( x^3y \right) ' \,dx -\int_{ }^{ } \left( y'x^3 \right)  \,dx     $$

$$ = \int_{ }^{ } x^3 \,dy + \left( x^3y \right) -\int_{ }^{ } y'x^3 \,dx    $$

$$  \left( yx^3 \right)'= x^3+ y \left( x^3 \right) ' ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{differentiation of 1st order } ~y  $$

$$  x^3= \left( yx^3 \right) '-y \left( x^3 \right) ' $$

$$  A=\int_{ }^{ } \left( \left( yx^3 \right) '-y \left( x^3 \right) ' \right)  \,dy+ x^3y-\int_{ }^{ } y'x^3 \,dx    $$

$$ = yx^3-\int_{ }^{ } y \left( x^3 \right) ' \,dy +x^3y-\int_{ }^{ } y'x^3 \,dx    $$

$$ = 2yx^3- \int_{ }^{ } y \left( x^3 \right) ' \,dy-\int_{ }^{ } y'x^3 \,dx $$

$$ = 2yx^3-  \underbrace{\left\{    \int_{ }^{ } y \left( x^3 \right) ' \,dy+\int_{ }^{ } y'x^3 \,dx \right\}}_{yx^3}  $$

$$  B:=\left\{    \int_{ }^{ } y \left( x^3 \right) ' \,dy+\int_{ }^{ } y'x^3 \,dx \right\} $$

Can I really reach to the solution continuing this way?

**ADD**

I think that using substitution of integration can finish a problem .

Comment: $y = y(x)$ so $$\int 3x^{2} y dx \ne 3y \int x^{2} dx$$ To solve, use that $$x^{3} y' + 3x^{2} y = (x^{3} y) '$$

Comment: Thank you for your advice . I will edit the post drastically .

Comment: You made a mistake/typo after substituting in $3x^{2} y = (x^{3} y)' - x^{3} y'$. You should have $$\therefore A = \int x^{3} \color{red}{y'} dx + \int \left( (x^{3} y)' - x^{3} y' \right) dx$$ and the $x^{3} y'$ integrands cancel. Then the solution follows. Your method is a bit overkill though \begin{align} x^{3} y' + 3 x^{2} y = e^{x} \implies (x^{3} y)' &= e^{x} \\ \implies \int (x^{3} y)' dx &= \int e^{x} dx \\ \implies x^{3} y &= e^{x} + c \\ \implies y &= \frac{e^{x} + c}{x^{3}} \end{align}

Comment: Woahh . Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bringing back the formula of $~ A ~$ .

$$  A= \int_{ }^{ } \left( x^3 \underbrace{\frac{  dy  }{ dx   }}_{y'}   \right)  \,dx+ \int_{ }^{ } 3x^2y \,dx     $$

$$ =  \int_{ }^{ } x^3 y' \,dx + \int_{ }^{ } 3x^2y \,dx  ~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{The knack is not to erase }~dx~~.  $$

$$ \left( x^3y \right) '= 3x^2y+y'x^3 $$

$$  \left( x^3y \right) '-y'x^3= 3x^2y $$

$$ \therefore ~~  A=  \int_{ }^{ } x^3 y' \,dx + \int_{ }^{ } \left( \left( x^3y \right) '-y'x^3 \right)  \,dx    $$

$$ =  \int_{ }^{ } x^3 y' \,dx + \left( x^3y \right) - \int_{ }^{ } y'x^3 \,dx   $$

$$ = x^3y $$